# How does GNOME Shell Extensions work?

Tags: gnome-shell

I have switched over to GNOME Shell, and use [GNOME Shell Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/) to tweak the looks and functionality of my distribution.

However, I have not yet found out what technology is used to install, enable and disable the extensions from the webpage with just a few clicks.

How is it implemented? Can any webpage do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is implemented using a browser plugin. "Gnome Shell Integration".

Try disabling it (firefox: addons -> plugins) and it no longer works.

Only the gnome website can use it.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome though, and there is no "visible" GNOME plugin installed.

Comment: chrome://plugins/